# Which web framework should i choose/ learn being a beginner in web dev

Tags: java, python, ruby-on-rails, django, grails

I am new to web development have a decent level of expertise in Java, a little bit in python.
Given this which platform do you think suits me well keeping freelancing in mind. Please help me out between django vs ror vs grails. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75798/django-vs-grails-vs

Answer (score 3):

It seems that django is somewhat easier than rails, so I would recommend going with that especially because you already have python experience.